# How can I call a method from another swift file in GameViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I have a button that I have created in storyboard that lives on my game game screen. It has an IB action in GameViewController() as follows:

```
   @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        GameScene().myCustomMethod()
    }
```

In my GameScene lives myCustomMethod() which will spawn enemies, however the code above doesn't work properly. If I add a `println("button was pressed")` in the IBAction, I get that print out in the console but myCustomMethod won't execute and spawn the enemies as expected.

Can anyone help me or explain how to resolve my issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method, you create a new `GameScene` object each time. You should only create it once (at initialization), and then always call `myCustomMethod` on this object.

```
var gameScene: GameScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    gameScene = GameScene()
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    gameScene.myCustomMethod()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! I am just struggling where to initialise gameScene = GameScene() in the GameViewController, what method?

Comment: Do you have an `init` or `viewDidLoad` method or something like this?

Comment: I have viewDidLoad but I am getting an error at the top class GameViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { ... } saying Class "GameViewController" has no initializers.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer; if you assign the variable `gameScene` in `viewDidLoad` rather than in `init`, it should be of type `GameScene!` (note the `!`)

Comment: Thanks, no more errors but I still can't change values across classes. For example my button code 

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    gameScene.booleanValue = true
}

But if I print booleanValue from gameScene().update(), the value is always false.

Comment: Sure that `buttonPressed` is connected properly?

Comment: Yeah because if I put a println("test") in the GameViewController IBAction, when I press the button I get "test" in the console.